# Htaccess Url to Virtual Directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, virtual, virtual-directory

Is there a way to have a Url in a custom virtual directory? Ex

http://mysub.domain.com/myurl/
to
http://mysub2.domain.com/virtualdirectory/

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean with virtual directory? Did you consider rewriting the URL in htaccess?

Comment: I mean, a directory that not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure you can have this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^virtualdirectory/(.*)$ /myurl/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Not works: RewriteRule ^virtualdirectory/(.*)$ /mysub.domain.com/myurl/ $1 [L,NC] -- the htaccess file is on the  http://mysub2.domain.com Root

Comment: Did you place `RewriteEngine On` before this line? Are there more rewrite rules? Is .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Yes htaccess works, it says me: The requested URL /mysub.domain.com/myurl/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Well in that rule worked. But probably `/mysub.domain.com/myurl/` isn't a valid URL. Left hand side is virtual but on right hand side you have to provide a working path

Answer (score 0):

Are both environments (mysub.domain and mysub2.domain) on the same hosting? If not, you need to redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^virtualdirectory/(.*)$ http://mysub2.domain.com/newdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Keep in mind: the user will see this. If you don't want the user to see this redirection, consider using a proxy (if the hosting supports this).

If both environments are on the same hosting, you can use the solution from anubhava, but it must be placed in the documentroot, as mentioned. If this is not working, check if you can access the effective directory on both environments.